# Relation of Boiling Point and Melting Point with the reactivity of an element

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

When we look at the trends of periodic table, there is an interesting correlation to be noticed. Along a period, when we look at the trends in reactivity of an element( Both due to electropositivity AND electronegativity) the trend is that from the right to the left, first there is a decrease and then an increase; which is definitely sensible. The question that arises is due to this observation that same happens with the boiling point and the melting point of that particular element. It first decreases and then increases. So this leads to the intuition that the reactivity (ie combining capacity ) also affects the physical characteristics of that particular element. If such is the case, the WHY EXACTLY does this happen- what is the explanation behind this phenomenon. If this intuition is false, then correction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and yes, you are awesome!

Comment: Yes there are trends in the periodic table. There are also many questions on Chemistry SE wondering why something seems out of place. Don't rely on trends - they can mislead. But, for a high-altitude view, what does a low melting point indicate about the strength of bonds in the solid?